# (Windows) Docker cannot create container

Tags: windows, docker

Собрали контейнеры на Линуксе, и понадобилось запустить на одной машине с Win 10 (Pro) чистая

Всего есть 4 контейнера
1. posgreSQL
2. PGadmin
3. frontend
4. backend

Первые два контейнера успешно запускаються командой docker-compose up -d, остальные два висят пока не вылетит ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Похожая ошибка как правило связана с настройками DNS, но всегда хостом выступал реальный сервер докера.
У нас же http://unix/drive/share.

Подскажите с чем может быть связана подобная ошибка и в какой сторону стоит копать?